# WebServiceContext is null when both SOAP and RESTful wars are bundled in a single EAR and deployed in WebSphere

Tags: rest, soap, websphere

In our application, the business logic lies in a different layer. The SOAP Web Service is already available. Now I'm developing REST support to that application.

The SOAP is designed to use @WebServiceProvider. The WebServiceContext is injected by @Resource. The REST is designed to be initialized during deployment or start of the server using ServletContextListener. SOAP is working when the REST war is not present in the EAR. But WebServiceContext is null when the REST war is added to the EAR.

Strangely, if I change the REST code to be initialized on each request by removing ServletContextListener, the SOAP works without any issue. But it adds the overhead of initializing the REST on each request.

```
 

    @WebServiceProvider(portName = "soapPort", 
                    serviceName = "soapService",
                    targetNamespace = "http://webservices.soap.test.com",
                    wsdlLocation = "test.wsdl")
    @ServiceMode(Mode.PAYLOAD)
    public class WebServiceProvider implements Provider {

      protected WebServiceContext context;

      @Override
      protected WebServiceContext getWebServiceContext() {
          return context;
      }

      @Resource
      public void setContext(final WebServiceContext context) {
          this.context = context;
      }

      @Override
      public Source invoke(final Source request) {
          return process(request);
      }
    }
```

SOAP and REST are working fine when it's deployed in JBoss. The problem occurs only when the EAR is deployed in WebSphere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing?  Are there any log messages, etc.? Also, can you post the REST code and the ServletContextListener code?  Also, what version of WebSphere are you using? Thanks

Comment: WebServiceContext is not getting initialized. So I get NullPointerException in the server log as the WebServiceContext  is null. I'm using WebSphere 9.0.5.

Comment: Are you using the built-in JAX-RS implementation for enabling REST?  It doesn't sound like it if you are disabling it with a servlet context listener.  If you use the built-in JAX-RS, I think this would work.  My suspicion is that your REST implementation is constructing an instance of your WebServiceProvider class that is not managed by the Java EE runtime in WebSphere - so then WebSphere has no control to inject the WebServiceContext.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Due to the time constraint, I needed to move ahead to implement the workaround. I created 2 separate EAR files. That solved the problem as of now. Yes, I'm using built-in JAX-RS. REST is working fine. Only JAX-WS is having problem when both wars are bundled in a single EAR file and only when deployed in WebSphere.